# Can't make outbound call using Plivo Android SDK

Tags: android, plivo

I just followed plivo android SDK documentation to make outbound call. I've register endpoint and assigned endpoint username and password to respective variable on plivo-android-example project. Also, I've assigned my mobile phone number to destination number. But when i try to run this project and hit call button, my phone doesn't get incoming call.

I am using trial account, and already register my phone number to sandbox number.

Any idea?

Comment: Got same problems. Did you fix this issue ? Support is not aswering ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

Did you attach your SIP Endpoint to the default Direct-Dial app? Check [here](https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/sip-endpoint/#using-a-default-dialer-app) for more details. Please make sure that you've added a valid caller ID in the answer url of the direct dial app. If you're still facing issues, please write to support@plivo.com and we can help you resolve this.